# Wants to develop ecom app in flutter and needs to show 3-4 categories screen back to back

Tags: flutter

I want something similar to fragments of android (1 home activity with 3-4 fragments on it ) but in flutter , I used Scaffold in home screen and added appbar , drawer and body , I want to always fix the app bar and only body will change dynamically according to data.

I also designed category screens i.e Home Cat , HomeSubCat etc , I just want to replace those screens in body of Home Screen.

data is like category, sub cat , sub sub cat and super cat

Please help me what should i do here , I am just beginner in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a PageView widget for this purpose.

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) you can find more details about pageview class.